# Why does the struct of ConfigMapVolumeSource not provide the Name field when I develop an operator to build a pod object

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

When I am developing an operator, I need to build a pod object. When I write pod.Spec.Volumes, what I need to mount is a configmap type, so I operate according to the structure in the core\v1 package to ConfigMapVolumeSource When I created the structure, I found that the name field of the configmap was not specified. There were only four other fields. The directory of my file was:

[image]

[image]

[image]
So when I build the pod, it will report an error. This field is required

[image]

Am I using the wrong version?
thank you very much for your help！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` field is inherited from `LocalObjectReference` struct.